# Passing secret text inside options block in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am looking to pass secret text "**webHookURL**" inside the options block to set url value inside office365ConnectorWebhooks as shown below

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    
    options {
        
        office365ConnectorWebhooks([[
            name: 'myConnector',
            startNotification: true,
            url: webHookURL,
            notifyFailure: true,
            notifySuccess: true
        ]])
        }
    }
```

Tried using withCredentials block but got error that withCredentials cannot be used inside options block.

Any idea how to set secret text value inside the options block.